# how to add attributed to nav bootstrap menues with fuel cms 1.3.1

Tags: fuelcms

I am trying to work with nav section and newly discovering it 
now i want to generate an menu like following :

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="products.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="products.php">Products 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php">Products 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php">Products 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="product_support.php">Product Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

With the code :

```
<?php echo $nav_arr = fuel_nav(array('depth'=>4
                        ,'render_type' => 'basic'
                        , 'group_id' => 1
                        ,'container_tag_attrs' => array('style' => '')
                        ,'container_tag_class' => 'nav navbar-nav menuright'
                        ,'order' => 'precedence'
                        ,'subcontainer_tag_class'=>array('dropdown-menu', 'styles' => array(0 => array(1 => 'dropdown')))
                        )); ?>
```

but cant getting the way to do the changes specially in this section

```
<li class="dropdown">
              <a href="products.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

the out put i am getting as follow :

```
       <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul style="" class="nav navbar-nav menuright">
    <li class="first"><a href="http://localhost/site/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/site/about us">about us</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/site/product" product-1>Product</a>
    <ul style="" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="first active"><a href="http://localhost/site/product-1">Product 1</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="http://localhost/site/product-2">product-2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/site/Product-Support">Product Support</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="http://localhost/site/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>
```

can one please help me out ????please view the source code of those list

Comment: So why you tag codeigniter ??

Comment: fuel cms based on codeigniter those in this case it may be impoper

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array` as `render_type` to manually generate desired tag.

Here is a example code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<?php 
$nav = fuel_nav(array('render_type' => 'array' ));
?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach($nav as $uri=>$item): 
        $classes='';
        $dropdown='';
        if($item['nav_key'] == $page_code) $classes .=' active';
        if(!empty($item['children'])) {
            $classes .=' dropdown';
            $dropdown ='class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"';
        }
    ?>
    <li class="<?=$classes?>">
        <a href="<?=BASE_URL?><?=$item['location']?>" <?=$dropdown?> ><?=$item['label']?></a>
        <?php if(!empty($item['children'])):?>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php foreach($item['children'] as $suburl=>$sub_item): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?=BASE_URL?><?=$sub_item['location']?>">
                    <?=$sub_item['label']?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```